# Use *#9900# to take log where to use this

Tags: android

I am getting this error Use `*#9900# to take log` where should I use this to take crash log.

I am not having eclipse or adt to see the logcat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must type this as if it were a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

It may be probably OEM key short cut to save sys dump in some specific folder.

You can check in your sdcard to view them

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the 'Phone' icon on your android as if you were about to dial a phone number.
2. Dial *#9900#
3. Select 'DELETE DUMPSTATE/LOGCAT' - second option from top.
4. When option 'delete Dump!' appears click on 'OK'
   This may or may not solve your problem but it will clear all the rubbish from your android.